# Zoom performance issue with world (admin 1 - States/province level) topojson map

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, geojson, topojson

I'm working with map where I could be selected visited region (states\province) on the whole world. And I found great instruments: [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) and [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki). Based on [Mike Bostock’s examples](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock) I created a wonderful map, but I got issue with zoom performance. I understand transformation would take a long time with such case where I have a lot of path elements, but I hope here is some better solution.

So, Is it possible to fix it via d3.js + topojson?

Or Should I change my view and look to a tile-based map?

Thanks!

```js
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;

    var worldGeoJson = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mrandreev/e03a6d104e5d17ef5f5138e1b36a4c1e/raw/804030989ea94f13de6b4917ddcc429f6268020c/world.json";

    var projection = d3.geo.patterson()
      .scale(210)
      .rotate([-11, 0])
      .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
      .precision(.1);

    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1, 50])
      .size([width, height])
      .on("zoom", onZoom);

    var svg = d3.select("#map")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .call(zoom);
    var g = svg.append("g");

    d3.json(worldGeoJson, function(error, world) {
      if (error) return console.error(error);

      g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "land")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.states).features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .append("title")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.properties.name;
        });

      g.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.mesh(world, world.objects.states, function(a, b) {
          return a.properties.countryCode !== b.properties.countryCode;
        }))
        .attr("class", "country")
        .attr("d", path);

      g.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.mesh(world, world.objects.states, function(a, b) {
          return a.properties.countrycode === b.properties.countrycode && a !== b;
        }))
        .attr("class", "region")
        .attr("d", path);
    });

    function onZoom() {
      var t = d3.event.translate;
      var s = d3.event.scale;

      t[0] = Math.max(Math.min(t[0], 0), width * (1 - s));
      t[1] = Math.max(Math.min(t[1], 0), height * (1 - s));

      zoom.translate(t);

      g.style("stroke-width", 1 / s)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + t + ")scale(" + s + ")");
    }
```

```css
.land {
  fill: #222;
}
.land:hover {
  fill: orange;
}

.country {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: .5px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.region {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: .2px;
  stroke-opacity: .25;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.geo.projection.v0.min.js"></script>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey. Have you a working jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: @Klaujesi sorry, my mistake, I have changed it on snippet

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888246/d3js-scaling-and-transition-performance and you can try this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25914/how-to-smooth-generalize-a-polygon-in-qgis